# I want to render the same div on the admin panel and frontend using shortcode in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am displaying vue build JS and CSS on my wordpress website. I have made a new plugin in the plugins directory and have made a new menu in the admin panel which works fine and displays the build content of the vue app.

[image]

I have a shortcode function `my_admin_page_callback()` in which I want to display the same content on the frontend of my website anywhere I want. This is my entire code in a single **main.php** file.

```
<?php

/*
Plugin Name: My Admin Plugin
Description: This plugin adds an admin dashboard view.
Version: 1.0
Author: Your Name
*/

function my_admin_menu_page() {
    add_menu_page(
        'My Admin Page',  // Page title
        'My Admin Plugin', // Menu title
        'manage_options',  // Capability required to access
        'my-admin-page',   // Menu slug
        'my_admin_page_callback', // Callback function to render content
        'dashicons-admin-plugins', // Icon URL or dashicon class
        20 // Menu position
    );
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_admin_menu_page');

function my_admin_page_callback() {
    ?>
        <h1>My Admin Page</h1>
        <div id="app">
        </div>

<?php 
}
function my_shortcode_function() { 
    ob_start();
    var_dump('Shortcode executed'); // Debug output
    ?>
    <div id="app">
        <!-- You can add content specific to the shortcode here -->
    </div>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('vue_shortcode', 'my_shortcode_function');


function enqueue_vue_script() {

    wp_enqueue_script('app-script', plugins_url('/testproject/dist/assets/index-d7bd537c.js', __FILE__), array(), null, true);
    wp_enqueue_style('app-style', plugins_url('/testproject/dist/assets/index-fc5f319f.css', __FILE__));

}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_vue_script');
```

Comment: You have to use `wp_enqueue_script` for frontend. You are using `admin_enqueue_scripts`. It will reflect only admin panel.

Comment: But if I use wp_enqueue_script will it still render on admin panel?

Comment: Yes. Render `admin_enqueue_scripts ` for admin and  `wp_enqueue_script ` for frontend. Both are different.

Comment: In what file do I do this?

Comment: In same plugin file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_vue_script');` hook for frontend.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: My Admin Plugin
Description: This plugin adds an admin dashboard view.
Version: 1.0
Author: Your Name
*/

function my_admin_menu_page() {
    add_menu_page(
        'My Admin Page',  // Page title
        'My Admin Plugin', // Menu title
        'manage_options',  // Capability required to access
        'my-admin-page',   // Menu slug
        'my_admin_page_callback', // Callback function to render content
        'dashicons-admin-plugins', // Icon URL or dashicon class
        20 // Menu position
    );
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_admin_menu_page');

function my_admin_page_callback() {
    ?>
        <h1>My Admin Page</h1>
        <div id="app">
        </div>

<?php 
}
function my_shortcode_function() { 
    ob_start();
    var_dump('Shortcode executed'); // Debug output
    ?>
    <div id="app">
        <!-- You can add content specific to the shortcode here -->
    </div>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('vue_shortcode', 'my_shortcode_function');


function enqueue_vue_script() {

    wp_enqueue_script('app-script', plugins_url('/testproject/dist/assets/index-d7bd537c.js', __FILE__), array(), null, true);
    wp_enqueue_style('app-style', plugins_url('/testproject/dist/assets/index-fc5f319f.css', __FILE__));

}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_vue_script');
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_vue_script');
```